# Telerik controls windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, telerik

Trying to implement a conversation view in a wp8.1 app using telerik controls, a platform im not familiar with. I keep getting a reference error on build:

```
Error   3   The name "RadPointerContentControl" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives".  D:\Visual Studio Workspace\Sports App\Sports App Prototype\Sports App Prototype\MainPage.xaml   74  29  Sports App Prototype
```

This error is really confusing me. I have referenced

```
xmlns:telerikPrimitives="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives"
```

in the XAML document but cannot seem to get it working properly, as if its just not seeing the reference properly, or is missing it at build time, tbh i havent a clue!

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: XAML

```
<Page xmlns:Maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps" 
  x:Class="Sports_App_Prototype.MainPage"
  xmlns:primitives="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assem‌​bly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="using:Sports_App_Prototype"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
      Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <Pivot>
        <Flyout x:Name="registration" >
            <Grid Height="320">
                <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,309">
                    Register New User or Login
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBox Margin="10,59,10,0" Text="Password">

                </TextBox>
                <TextBox Margin="10,16,10,0" Text="Username">

                </TextBox>
                <CheckBox Margin="172,99,0,0" Content="Accept">

                </CheckBox>
                <Button Content="Register/Login" Margin="10,99,0,164">

                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Flyout>
        <PivotItem Header="map view">
            <StackPanel>
                <Maps:MapControl Height="450" Width="355" />
                <Button x:Name="FilterButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Filter_Click" Content="Filter" Margin="126,0,126.667,0" Height="61"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </PivotItem>
        <Flyout x:Name="Filter">
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>
                        Filter Users
                    </TextBlock>
                    <RichTextBlock>
                        <!-- Stuff goes here for RTB -->
                    </RichTextBlock>
                    <CheckBox>
                        Dynamically generated from user #1
                    </CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox>
                        Dynamically generated from user #2
                    </CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox>g
                        Dynamically generated from user #3
                    </CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox>
                        Dynamically generated from user #4
                    </CheckBox>

                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Flyout>
        <PivotItem Header="chat">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="12">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <telerikPrimitives:RadPointerContentControl Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                                                         TargetPoint="-150,-300">
                        <telerikPrimitives:RadPointerContentControl.PointerTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Polygon Width="12"
                                         Height="24"
                                         Points="0,0 12,0 12,12 0,24"
                                         StrokeThickness="0"
                                         Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                                         RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                                    <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                                    </Polygon.RenderTransform>
                                </Polygon>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </telerikPrimitives:RadPointerContentControl.PointerTemplate>

                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       Margin="12"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TimeStamp}"
                                       Margin="12, 0, 12, 12"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </telerikPrimitives:RadPointerContentControl>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is complaining that it cannot find the reference to the .DLL. Under references in Visual Studio, do you have the file called Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives added? If so, then please post your entire XAML file and I'll help you troubleshoot it.

BTW, make sure you are using a Silverlight WP8.1 app and not a WinRT app.

Comment: Thanks. Project is targeting Windows Phone 8.1

Posted XAML into my question. Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives is referenced. Thanks for your help. Also: http://picpaste.com/Screenshot__1_-JYXrKWWA.png for errors

Comment: Change your xmlns to : xmlns:telerikPrimitives="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives"

Comment: Hold up... is this a Silverlight WP 8.1 project as shown in this pic: http://screencast.com/t/66J2JMWt9j

Comment: Nope, so do I need to recreate the project or can i retarget it?

Comment: Telerik controls ATM will only work with a Silverlight WP project.

Comment: Great thanks, will post back once ive created the new project though im sure the issue will disappear! Thank you very much for you kind help.